# Data Frame- Remove all after year but keep information about year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, split

My DF looks like below:

```
id date
1  21 July 2023 (abcd)
2  22 July 2023 00:00:01
3  23 July 2023 -abcda
```

I need to remove all after year (2023) but I want to keep it. So the result should be:

```
id date
1  21 July 2023
2  22 July 2023
3  23 July 2023
```

I used this but I can't keep information about year

```
df['date'].str.rsplit('2023', 1).str.get(0)
```

I can't add year '2023' to the string that would left after this operation because the year can change. But I can deal with this. I just need to get the result.

Regards
Tomasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove everything after the 4 digits of the year:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace(r'(?<=\b\d{4}\b).*', '', regex=True)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VeyHAa/1)

Or with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to match digits, letters, and 4 digits:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.extract(r'(\d+ [a-zA-Z]+ \d{4})')
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uCFNml/1)

*NB. if you only want to split after **2023** and not any 4 digits year, then replace `\d{4}` by `2023`.*

Output:

```
   id          date
0   1  21 July 2023
1   2  22 July 2023
2   3  23 July 2023
```

A variant of your original approach would have been to split with a regex lookbehind, but it's less efficient since you need 2 `str` operations:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.split(r'(?<=2023)', regex=True).str.get(0)
```

Comment: I used  your first solution and it work great! Second left me NaN values when it can't find a '2023'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove text after 2023 from the date column, then you can simply achieve this by

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.split('2023')[0] + '2023')
```

This code specifically targets the 'date' column and removes text after '2023' in each cell, keeping only the content before '2023' and appending '2023' back to it.